# matching string patterns in java

Tags: java, regex, string, jakarta-ee

I am trying to match a string to another such that at least 3 characters match between the two. My string should be of exact length 4, all capitals, 3 letters and 1 digit between 0 and 10 (excluding 0 and 10). eg : RM5Z 
How can I do that in java in the most simplified form?

Comment: I'm sure you tried something, but it did not work, right? Please show your code, even if it failed to get the results that you wanted. It is easier to fix someone else's code than to write one from scratch.

Comment: Does it mean that you did it with a not simplified form? can you show us?

Comment: I was using substrings to match substrings with multiple OR's and AND's. I was not familiar with regex and running through some examples, it seems it would be 3-4 lines of code instead of a huge method with nested if's that I used.
Yes the letters could repeat.

Comment: Sequence matters like RM5Z is same as RMZ5 or they are different ?

Comment: RM5Z is different from RMZ5

Answer (score 4):

To check form of your string you can use this `^(?=[A-Z]*[1-9][A-Z]*$).{4}$` regex

- `^.{4}$` will ensure length 4
- `^(?=[A-Z]*[1-9][A-Z]*$)` will accept only strings that contains digit in range 1-9 that can be surrounded with letters A-Z

Not sure if this is the way you want to check your Strings, let me know

```
static boolean testStrings(String a, String b) {

    if (isValid(a) && isValid(b)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            a = a.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(b.charAt(i)), "");
        }
        return a.length() <= (4 - 3);
    }else
        return false;

}

static boolean isValid(String s) {
    return s.matches("^(?=[A-Z]*[1-9][A-Z]*$).{4}$");
}
```

Comment: This solution is simple yet great, solves more than half of the problem

Comment: Thanks for the regex but I am looking at a simpler solution for the other part.Matching every single character of string with every single character of the other (and passing it if it has 3 matches) is something that I am trying to avoid.
esp because the positions can be different 
eg : CPRT and C3RT, CPRT and CP8T, CPRT and CPR9 are all success scenarios.
and we know that there is at least one digit but there can also be two. eg: WD2L and W72L is also a success scenario.

Comment: @neoInfinite oh, so position doesn't matter... I was mislead by your previous comment `RM5Z is different from RMZ5`

Comment: @neoInfinite since characters can repeat and its position doesn't matter maybe try removing once each character from first string that exists in second string. You can do it with `.replaceFirst()`. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know whether two strings of length 4 have three characters in common and you know all the chars are in a restricted range, then you can just intersect bitsets and count the bits thus:

```
public static boolean haveNCharsInCommon(String a, String b, int n) {
  BitSet charsInA = charsIn(a);
  BitSet charsInB = charsIn(b);
  charsInA.and(charsInB);
  return charsInA.cardinality() >= n;
}

private BitSet charsIn(String s) {
  BitSet bs = new BitSet();
  for (int i = 0, n = s.length(); i < n; ++i) {
    bs.set(s.charAt(i);
  }
  return bs;
}
```

If the strings could contain arbitrary codepoints you would probably want to use a sparse vector instead of a bitset.

Comment: The characters can be capital letters or digits from 1 to 9.

Comment: @neoInfinite, I see that in the OP.  In "letters", do you include non-Latin characters like the Greek capital delta ('Δ')?  Are you suggesting that this code should reject inputs that violate this constraint?

Comment: Thanks for your solution Mike. And, yes exactly. I am sorry I was not very clear before, but code should reject anything apart from english capital alphabets and digits from 1-9.

Comment: I think Pshemo provides a fine way to validate the inputs.  You could use the same `charsIn` and intersect it with a bitset containing just the letters and check that the cardinality of the intersection is 3, then check that the cardinality of the intersection with the bitset containing digits is 1, and that the overall length is 4.  That's probably less straightforward than Pshemo's solution though.